# Why is the DateTimePicker's MaxDateTime 12/31/9998 23:59:59?

Tags: c#, winforms

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.maxdate.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.maxdatetime.aspx

This value seems arbitrary when no explanation is provided. Why isn't this just DateTime.MaxValue?

Comment: Interestingly, that value appears to be exactly 1 year before `DateTime.MaxValue`.

Comment: Set it so high that we don't have to worry about it for another 8000 odd years?

Comment: Why is your question tagged [wpf] when you're asking about a WinForms control...? (And why do people think this is off-topic? This question will do alright here.)

Comment: does this really matter anybody? I guess having all 9 in the year could lead in some cases to a trial to round up to next day, eventually, depending on control usage or rounding or time setting and if it would move from 9999 to the next day 1 more digit would be required... but who cares comeon !

Comment: @Davide Piras: Apparently JSWork and the two people who upvoted the question care.

Comment: It is no DateTime.MaxValue because it is Calendar.MaxSupportedDateTime.  Different cultures have different calendars.

Comment: @HansPassant: MSDN disagrees on two counts. 1) The default value of MaxSupportedDateTime is the year 9999, which is a different value. Relying on this would cause a crash 2) According to MSDN, the datepicker's max value is a readonly constant, not culture dependent.

Comment: Use Reflector or the Reference Source to have a look-see.

Answer (score 1):

There probably isn't a business reason.  I don't think it's a coincidence that the value is exactly one year prior to `DateTime.MaxValue`.  The DateTimePicker may have some internal logic that paginates the adjacent months that breaks near `DateTime.MaxValue` that wasn't worth special casing.